# Problems with EditText(... string_split ...)

Tags: android, string, split, android-edittext

My LogCat Output

```
01-05 21:04:22.299: D/info(2699): Lenght b = 0
01-05 21:04:22.299: D/info(2699): Lenght Split = 0
01-05 21:04:22.299: D/info(2699): Item = 25.8
01-05 21:04:22.299: D/info(2699): Länge = 4
```

My Question:

From my understanding Lenght b and Split should be 2 and b[0]=25 + b[1]=8...

b[0] + b[1] are empty...

What is the problem with my code?

**java:**

```
    public class ButtonCreateLocationOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final EditText editTextLocationName = (EditText) formElementsView.findViewById(R.id.editTextLocationName);
            if ((editTextLocationName.getText().toString().length() > 0) && (StringDescription.length() > 0))){
                String Test = editTextLocationName.getText().toString();
                String[] b = Test.split(".");
                Log.d("info", "Lenght b = " + b.length);
                for (String string : b) {
                    Log.d("info", string);
                }
                String[] itemsName = editTextLocationName.getText().toString().split(".");
                Log.d("info", "Lenght Split = " + itemsName.length);
                Log.d("info", "Item = " + editTextLocationName.getText().toString());
                Log.d("info", "Länge = " + editTextLocationName.getText().toString().length());
            }
        }//onClick
    }//OnClickListener
```

Comment: > Layout xml:

> <EditText
> android:id="@+id/editTextLocationName"; 
android:layout_width="match_parent"; 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"; 
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"; 
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"; 
android:ems="10"; 
android:hint="Location Name"; 
android:inputType="numberDecimal"; 
android:singleLine="true"; />

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the dot, otherwise it will interpret it as if it was a RegularExpression.

Change the split line to `String[] b = Test.split("\\.");`

Answer (score 0):

The [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) accepts a regex as a parameter. If you look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) you'll see that a dot is a special character in regex's.

Try escaping it like so: `"45.2".split("\\.")`.